# How to make a navigation controller always show its first viewcontroller when appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tabbed view controller with 4 different tabs. A tab is called "Saved" which takes you to a Navigation Controller.

This Navigation controller initially shows a ViewController which is a grid of all the photos you have saved using the app. If you click on one it takes you to the individual profile of that image. If you click on the username in this individual profile it takes you to the user who posted the photo's page etc.

The problem is that when you go to another tab and then return to this one, you see the last page you were viewing (for example the profile of who posted one of your saved photos) but I'd like it to show the initial viewController it is trying to show which is the grid showing all your saved photos.

The question is how can I get the NavigationController you land on when pressing the tab to show its first view controller and not the last one that the user was on?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840978/ios-tabbed-application-with-table-view-how-to-reset-table-view-tab-beginner

Comment: @rmaddy, should we close it as a duplicate then?

Comment: @DuncanC I didn't close as a dupe because the other is in Objective-C and it only offers a high level description of the solution.